# Using promises stops variable being set

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code sets the row.already_messaged_clients absolutely fine and is accessible outside of the loop.

```
businesses.forEach(async function(row) {
// let already_messaged_clients_arr = await getAlreadyMessagedClientsForPlaceID(row.place_id);
row.already_messaged_clients = 3;
});
```

When I use an await like this:

```
businesses.forEach(async function(row) {
let already_messaged_clients_arr = await getAlreadyMessagedClientsForPlaceID(row.place_id);
row.already_messaged_clients = 3;
});
```

row.already_messaged_clients does not get set. Why is this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `await` does what it says and *waits* for `getAlreadyMessagedClientsForPlaceID` to finish before continuing. Which, in turn, means that every statement after the `await` also has to wait.

Comment: Does getAlreadyMessagedClientsForPlaceID actually resolve at some point? Until it resolves the function execution will be suspended and the property wont get set

Comment: Yes it resolves, I can print out the result of getAlreadyMessagedClientsForPlaceID

Comment: Suhel Khan's answer works, why does it work with a normal loop but not a foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a 'for...of' loop instead of 'forEach'

```
for (let row of businesses) {
  let already_messaged_clients_arr = await 
  getAlreadyMessagedClientsForPlaceID(row.place_id);
  row.already_messaged_clients = 3;
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Why does it work with a normal loop but not a foreach?

Comment: because the normal loop is synchronous while the forEach loop is asynchronous.

Comment: @SuhelKhan erm, no. `.forEach` is synchronous but if it executes async functions, they'll still finish later. `for..of` is not "synchronous" given that it works with async code. It just works in the same mode as the rest of the function.